# Swift and JSON driving me crazy

Tags: json, swift, serialization

I am really getting stuck on this.
I have created a JSON service, that returns data like this:

```
[
    {
        "docNameField": "Test",
        "docNumField": 22832048,
        "docVerField": 1,
        "docDataBaseField": "Legal",
        "docCheckedOutWhenField": "03/05/2020",
        "whereCheckedOutField": "PC0X8J9RD"
    }
]
```

This is Postman output.

No matter how I try, I cannot seem to be able to put together the correct combination og HTTP call, deserialization, types and so on to get a list of objects out in the end.

This func below outputs this:

> JSON String: Optional("[{\"docNameField\":\"Test\",\"docNumField\":22832048,\"docVerField\":1,\"docDataBaseField\":\"Legal\",\"docCheckedOutWhenField\":\"03/05/2020\",\"whereCheckedOutField\":\"PC0X8J9RD\"}]")

```
func LoadLockedDocumentsByDocnum(docNum:Int32) {
    let json: [String: Any] = ["action":"getCheckedOutDocuments","adminUserName":"\(APPuserName)","adminPassword":"\(APPuserPassword)","adminDomain":"\(APPuserDomain)","applicationKey":"19730905{testKey}","searchTerm":docNum]
           let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    self.documentEntries.removeAll()

    let url = URL(string: "https://{URL}//CheckOut")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") //Optional
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request)  { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if let resultat = response as! HTTPURLResponse?{
            if resultat.statusCode == 200{
                if error != nil {
                }
                else {
                    print(data!)
    if let nydata = data{
        print("JSON String: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))")
                }  
                }
            }}
}
dataTask.resume()
```

}

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please read [ask] and provide a [example] to improve your question.

Comment: Hi Picode,
I have edited the question to include code as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have come pretty close. To get a list of objects out, you first need to declare that object:

```
struct MyResponseObject: Decodable { // please give this a better name
    let docNameField: String
    let docNumField: Int
    let docVerField: Int
    let docDataBaseField: String
    let docCheckedOutWhenField: Date
    let whereCheckedOutField: String
}
```

And then use a `JSONDecoder` to deserialise the JSON. Instead of:

```
print("JSON String: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))")
```

write:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
do {
    // here's your list of objects!
    let listOfObjects = try decoder.decode([MyResponseObject].self, from: data!)
} catch let error {
    print(error) // an error occurred, you can do something about it here
}
```